# multiple ternary operators in wordpress/php

Tags: php, wordpress, ternary-operator

I am working on a php code as shown below:

```
$special_reports = new \WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'cpac-special-report',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => $data->{"toggle_status"} == 3 ? 2 : 4,
    'posts_per_page' => $data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 1 ? 3 : 4,
    'posts_per_page' => $data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 2 ? 1 : 4,
    'posts_per_page' => $data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 3 ? 2 : 4,
    'posts_per_page' => $data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 4 ? 3 : 4
]);
```

I want to minimize the above php code and use multiple ternary operators. This is what **I have tried** but I am not getting the desired o/p.

```
$special_reports = new \WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'cpac-special-report',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => $data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 1 ? 3 : $data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 2 ? 1 : $data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 3 ? 2 : $data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 4 ? 1:4
]);
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code which I have tried above so that when,

```
$data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 1 then it should print 3
$data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 2 then it should print 1
$data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 3 then it should print 2
$data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 4 then it should print 3
```

Comment: $data->{"toggle_status"} has no matter and http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f380ae3102cfd08236fef84d4b94d195cdbcda05

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap it in parentheses:

```
$special_reports = new \WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'cpac-special-report',
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => $data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 1 ? 3 : 
                             ($data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 2 ? 1 : 
                               ($data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 3 ? 2 : 
                                 ($data->{"toggle_multi_status"} == 4 ? 1:4)))
    ]);
```

Comment: Still this is very hard to read, I think it's OK for if/else if, but neasting so many ternany operators make the code very unreadable. Maybe you should go with another approach to check $data->{"toggle_multi_status"} value, like switch for example